# Virtualization platform for WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Which virtualization platforms are supported for WSO2 Enterprise Integrator (ESB)?

I mean virtualization platforms like VmWare, Microsoft Hyper-V, Xen etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 ESB can run on most of the virtualization platforms. Out of the box, support is available for following platforms.
https://wso2.com/integration/install

1.[docker](https://github.com/wso2/docker-ei)

2.[docker-compose](https://github.com/wso2/docker-ei/tree/master/docker-compose)

3.[vagrant](https://github.com/wso2/vagrant-ei)

4.[kubernetes/openshift](https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-ei)

Comment: Thanks. What is about VMware ESX/ESXi? Technically I understand that it’s not a problem but I can be the issue in the support case.

Comment: We haven't tested on ESX/ESXi. But there is no technical limitation AFAIU.

Comment: I was wondering since ESX/ESXi is just a hypervisor, if there is a way to run Docker on top of the ESX/ESXi, we should be  able to use docker-ei file with that. Also Please note that WSO2 EI is the successor of WSO2 ESB